# TypeHinting tuples in Python

Tags: python, type-hinting

When I want to typehint a tuple in Python like:

```
def func(var: tuple[int, int]):
    # do something

func((1, 2))    # would be fine
func((1, 2, 3)) # would throw an error
```

It is required to give the exact number of items in the tuple. That's different from list typehinting:

```
def func(var: list[int]):
    # do something

func([1])       # would be fine
func([1, 2])    # would also be fine
func([1, 2, 3]) # would also be fine
```

That's consequentially, in a way, because of the type of tuples. Because they are designed not to be changed, you have to hardcode the amount of items in it.

So my question is, is there a way to make the number of items in a tuple type hint flexible? I tried something like that but it didn't work:

```
def func(var: tuple[*int]):
```

Comment: Just a note: if you need a tuple containing a variable number, you should think whether you should use a list instead. Maybe a tuple is still the right choice, but usually a list would be better in this case.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Yes, you can *make the number of items in a tuple type hint flexible*.

From Python 3.9 and on you can do:

```py
def func(var: tuple[int, ...]):
    pass
```

Before Python 3.9 you would do:

```py
from typing import Tuple

def func(var: Tuple[int, ...]):
    pass
```

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple

> To specify a variable-length tuple of homogeneous type, use literal ellipsis, e.g. `tuple[int, ...]`. A plain `tuple` is equivalent to `tuple[Any, ...]`, and in turn to `tuple`.

Comment: I got the error `Argument "object" to "function" of "class" has incompatible type "List[Tuple[Any]]"; expected "List[Tuple[Any, ...]]"`. It seems to me that `List[Tuple[Any]]` should equal `List[Tuple[Any, ...]]`, no? Eg, list(tuple(object)) == list(tuple(object, object))? I am also using mypy.

Comment: No, you should receive the error notes `"List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance` `Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant`, i.e. `Sequence[tuple[Any]]`.

Answer (score 66):

Starting with [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) it is possible to use builtin typings without importing the `typing` module, so starting with Python 3.9, `Tuple[...]` has been deprecated in favor of `tuple[...]`. e.g.

```py
def func(var: tuple[int, ...]):
    pass
```

Comment: Wasn't this introduced in Python 3.10?

Comment: @Pyzard check the [3.9 Release Notes](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-390/), it includes PEP585. Conversely PEP585 is also labeled python-version 3.9.