# How to type hint a tuple in python?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have one line of code:

```
a = tuple((1,2,3,4)[idx] for idx in range(4))
```

And PyCharm gives the following type hint:
a: tuple[Any, ...] = tuple((1,2,3,4)[idx] for idx in range(4))

Why is it tuple[Any, ...] instead of tuple[int]?

Comment: because that is the information it is capable of inferring on it's own.

Comment: Is the title actually your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeHinting tuples in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533787/typehinting-tuples-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

the type of a `tuple` consist of every type of each element within the `tuple`

In your case `typing.Tuple[int,...]` or `typing.Tuple[Any,...]` is correct

[Typing Tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple)